# Difference encodeURIComponent in JS and Uri.EscapeDataString in .NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, encodeuricomponent

I have the following two lines of code.

JS:
`var chars = encodeURIComponent(input).split("");`

VB.NET:
`Dim chars As Char() = Uri.EscapeDataString(input).ToCharArray`

Should they in theory not provide the same output?
In some cases the byte array length is longer in .NET than in JS->breaking my followup code.

The suggestions i have found on stackoverflow have changed nothing (changing target framework e.g.. (Current one is 4.61)

Is there no direct equivalent in for encodeURIComponent in .NET then?

Comment: First, you should post some examples that produce different outputs. Second, you should to give more details about the application that will run your vb.net code ¿Is it a web site, a web application, a desktop application?

Comment: @MauricioOrtega Thanks for your answer, i figured it might be another problem maybe. I have a couple of functions that do encryption and decryption together. I can't exactly replicate the behaviour of the js functions in .net. Maybe it is not possible, maybe i am doing something wrong. I will debug some more and try to give as much information as possible. My application will be a windows desktop application, sending and receiving encrypted or compresses json messages. What i noticed so far is that my function will return gibberish once the byte length goes over 255.

Comment: Well. As far as I understand, you can't or are not authorized to edit the js side code (that which acts as server) but you need to replicate that behavior in .net to send a valid portion of data to an api who expects that data to be constructed by the js encode+encrypt functions it trusts on. If you have access to the js sources you could use ine of the multiple ways to run js code into a .net application wrapping the js code and porting it to .net methods (like as a pinvoke)